# How to access the build-in microphone and camera in wechat running on linux?

Tags: webcam, microphone, docker, soundcard, speakers

I can talk with my friend and watch images each other in `skype`,that is to say that built-in microphone and speaker can be used in `skype` on my Ubuntu OS.

There is no `wechat`'s official version running on Linux,`wechat` only can run on android,iPhone,mac,windows.
Some geeker use docker to build `wechat` in Linux this way:

```
docker pull bestwu/wechat
xhost +
docker run -d --name wechat --device /dev/snd \
           -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
           -v $HOME/WeChatFiles:/WeChatFiles \
           -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \
           -e XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx \
           -e QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx \
           -e GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx \
           -e AUDIO_GID=`getent group audio | cut -d: -f3` \
           -e GID=`id -g` \
```

Now to input `wechat` in terminal,i can use it to input text ,i can hear friend's voice ,but he can't hear my voice,no image can be showed on screen(the image can be shown in `cheese` and `skype`),
the  built-in microphone and camera can't be used in `wechat`.How can fix it?

The possible way :

#### electron-wechat

[image]

```
Installed ,can't be start successfully.
```

#### wechat on web

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should consider [filing an issue here](https://github.com/bestwu/docker-wechat/issues)

Comment: I got more care than github.

Comment: @showkey did you try my solution? if web.wechat.com is disabled by WeChat itself, the electron wrapper won't work either. Then the last thing you can do is to try to install it on PlayOnLinux. You may download the Windows executable and install it on PlayOnLinux.

Comment: Let us know the Linux flavour you have and version. I got it working with PlayOnLinux, if you share some details I would be able to help.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1455169/233195

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is no way to do the job with some geek way,it is wechat's duty to create a linux version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[WeChat Electron](https://gitlab.com/code4people/wechat-electron/-/jobs/877044638/artifacts/file/dist/wechat-electron-linux-x64/deb/wechat-electron_1.0.0_amd64.deb). I've built this. It's a debian package.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have now might be half cooked. Instead of trying to fix the docker solution, you might wanna try this [WeChat on Linux](https://itsfoss.com/install-wechat-desktop-client-in-ubuntu/). Hope this helps you. Until WeChat officially releases a desktop version for linux, you would wanna stick with [WeChat Web](https://web.wechat.com/) Could you confirm you're in need of a desktop version and don't wanna go through the solutions provided [here](https://itsfoss.com/install-wechat-desktop-client-in-ubuntu/)? Someone can help you by building a wrapper for https://web.wechat.com/ using Electron framework [ElectronJS](https://www.electronjs.org/). The second solution [here](https://itsfoss.com/install-wechat-desktop-client-in-ubuntu/) mentioned deprecated is nothing but the same. May be this information is too much technical but you can always comment and I'll be able to help you.

Comment: @showkey I think you tried for rambox and failed. I don't use WeChat but I'll create an open source project in GitLab and try to build one for you. I can't comment on your question but here as I'll have to have a certain reputation score to comment on somebody's question. If you have questions please comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Electronic WeChat is a unoffical WeChat client, a better WeChat app built with Electron. To install the Electronic WeChat snap package on all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install electronic-wechat
```

This app is based on Wechat web app (https://wx.qq.com/), Tencent (the
WeChat vendor) has denied new user login from the web app for some
reason, but you can continue to use this app if you can login to the web app.