# Can I install WeChat in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu

Recently, I read some blogs regarding installation of WeChat in ubuntu 22.04. Is it feasible?

Comment: I would recommend reading the [How do I ask a good question](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) page, specifically *"Search, and Research ..."*.  What have you found?  What have you *tried*?  What problems have you run into?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. For a while I'd been using wine to run the Windows version of WeChat. I'm a (relatively) new WeChat user, and the web version of WeChat (and anything using that or an equivalent API) weren't allowed for my account. I found running WeChat under wine quite frustrating. Fonts, emojis, and file sharing were buggy.

I recently discovered [this webpage](https://www.ubuntukylin.com/applications/106-cn.html) offering a 64-bit Debian package designed for Ubuntu Kylin. The webpage is in Chinese; my translation tells me

> As a national APP, WeChat has become an indispensable part of our
> daily life. However, there is a certain gap between the WeChat
> alternatives under the current Linux distribution and the original
> version, which greatly affects the daily work efficiency of users and
> their daily audio-visual entertainment needs. In order to further
> enrich and improve the ecological needs of Ubuntu Kylin users and
> provide a smoother communication environment, Kylin Software and
> Tencent jointly promoted the native WeChat adaptation work based on
> the Linux platform. store shelves. Users who want to experience it
> just need to search for "WeChat" in Kylin Store, complete the
> installation with one click, and scan the code to log in to chat at
> any time.

You can install it by

```
wget http://archive.ubuntukylin.com/software/pool/partner/weixin_2.1.4_amd64.deb
dpkg -i weixin_2.1.4_amd64.deb
```

You can see all the available debs at https://archive.ubuntukylin.com/software/pool/partner/. Some of the other ones look useful too. As of Feb. 2023, the latest WeChat version is 2.1.4, but there are older versions there too and newer ones might be posted in the future, who knows.

Ubuntu Kylin users can just do

```
apt install weixin
```

For non-Kylin users, it is probably possible to add the relevant ppa and also install it via app

You can launch it by using the command

```
weixin
```

or looking for weixin in the usual place you search for your apps. It's a real game changer. Everything works smoothly so far in the app (fonts, emojis, file transfer etc), though some menus are in Chinese.

Comment: Please note that these binaries in `archive.ubuntukylin.com` have not been maintained (for 2-4 years now) and are thus will likely contain severe security vulnerabilities...

Answer (score 1):

I have now two WeChat running on my Ubuntu 22.04.

One uses "deepin-wine", here an esxaustive guide for easy installation: https://ossmalta.eu/how-to-install-deepin-wechat-qq-im-in-ubuntu-20-04-the-easy-way/. Just two command line:

*wget -O- https://deepin-wine.i-m.dev/setup.sh | sh*

then

*sudo apt install com.qq.weixin.deepin*

This will install the 32bit version, and (for me) it works far better than the 64bit I used to install using WineHQ

I got problems saving files and browsing the folders to send one (but I got general problems with Nautilus). The drag-and-drop works fine. Audio and Video calls work smoothly and all the features, like translation, are present, including the notification icon on top.
[WeChat deepin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH22Y.png)

The second one is the Weixin, the Ubuntu Kylin suggested by **innisfree**, audio and video calls are missing here but looks stable. After an easy installation, I wasn't able to execute Weixin, I had to change permissions for /home/x/.config/weixin

Update: there is no translation (I have many Chinese contacts) and you cannot quote a message in your answers.

Thank you

P.S. sorry if my posts aren't in a perfect "askubuntu" style, newby here.

Comment: Hi and welcome! While your answer addresses the issue, we would encourage you to summarize the solution and use the link as a reference. This is because links can break over time and render your answer useless.

Comment: Hi, and thank you, Tommy, it makes sense and I will make good use of your advise!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: https://github.com/ferdium, It includes wechat too.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion it's highly appreciated but I did not find WeChat.

Comment: WeChat is installed but not working; it says error!

Answer (score 0):

Ferdium uses the WeChat web-based version, no longer supported by Tencent. I have just succeded using deepin-wine.